# collapsible menu using knockout and jquery

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to build a simple collapsible menu using knockout and jquery. But for some reason jquery is not being activated.

the script is located here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DXymk/)

```
    <ul id="usernav" data-bind="template: { name: 'seasonTemplate', foreach: seasons, as: 'season' }"></ul>

<script type="text/html" id="seasonTemplate">
    <li>
        <strong data-bind="text: name"></strong>
        <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'monthTemplate', foreach: months, as: 'month' }"></ul>
    </li>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="monthTemplate">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: month"></span>
        is in
        <span data-bind="text: season.name"></span>
    </li>
</script>
```

the script is

```
        var viewModel = {
        seasons: ko.observableArray([
            { name: 'Spring', 
             months:[ 'March' , 'April', 'May'  ]},
            { name: 'Summer', months: [ 'June', 'July', 'August' ] },
            { name: 'Autumn', months: [ 'September', 'October', 'November' ] },
            { name: 'Winter', months: [ 'December', 'January', 'February' ] }
        ])
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

$('#usernav').find('ul').hide();

$('li').click(function(e) {
    $(this).children('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Edit:-**
 So yes I may have forgotten to include the jquery library in the original jsfiddle post while copy pasting, but that is not my issue. I created a separate question regarding my issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730723/jquery-eventbinding-in-collpasible-menu-while-using-knockout-template)
Thanks!!

Comment: You forgot to attach jquery lib to your fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/DXymk/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Help us help you first by updating your jsFiddle.

If this is NOT your answer, i'll delete it myself, but, fixing jquery library made your code work, so this 'might' be an answer (sic).

[image: screen capture of jsfiddle libraries]

On jsFiddle, update your javascript libraries and ADD jquery.

`Your` [resulting jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DXymk/2/)

Comment: No comment? Wo, this is halloween. At least, upvote it for beeing an answer 'way out' of what we'd expect it to be.

Comment: sorry i was ready to except it as answer the 9 minute rule delayed it to more than that. Thanks!!. That was a good catch but that was not part of my problem. the fiddle works but the same fails in my MVC project.i will post another question

Answer (score 1):

For people who are still facing this problem working out the jquery mobile and knockoutjs for getting the ui correct, you have to force a refresh after the observablearray has been reassigned.

```
$('.selector').collapsibleset('refresh');
```